# How a const widget works with its children?

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's say I have this `HomePage` widget:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(),
    );
  }
}
```

I am able to use a const constructor at the root (`MaterialApp` widget) because all children do have const constructors too.

If I add the `AppBar` widget, I will have to remove the const constructor from the root, because `AppBar` does not have a const constructor.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp( // no const anymore
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(...),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But why am I able to use the `HomePage` widget with a const constructor ? See code below:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const HomePage(); // using a const constructor
  }
}
```

I thought it would be impossible because of the `AppBar` child widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `HomePage` class is immutable. The `build` function *implementation* doesn't affect it.

The `const` keyword can be used when the object is immutable. A Compiler allocates the same portion of memory for all objects.

For more info, reference the [Using constructors: Dart doc](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors)

Comment: Yes I know, MaterialApp too is immutable, but I can't use its const constructor while building the HomePage widget. I think there should a difference between when you define the widget and when you use it in a build method. while defining, the widget is not aware of its children. As long as its state is immutable we can create a const constructor. But inside a build method, we can use the const constructor only if all children do have const constructor too. I think it is not obvious from the docs.